# dataframe from a str format data

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataset which looks like this,

```
x
a: krb
x
c: HK
a: HP
d: T
x
c: CN
a: MSS
d: H-MSS
```

x is the separator. I would want the data in a dataframe in the following format,

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
x       null    a: krb  null
x       c:HK    a: HP   d:T
x       c:CN    a: MSS  d:H-MSS
```

Comment: the order doesn't matter and the spark version is 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this using `pivot`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Read data as an rdd
rdd = sc.textFile('xxxxxxxxxx')

# Map each row to the column it will be in
mapping = {'a': 'col3', 'c': 'col2', 'd': 'col4'}
df = rdd.map(lambda x: (mapping.get(x[0]), x)).toDF(['colname', 'value'])

# create a row indicator
df = df.withColumn('order', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df.withColumn('row', F.expr("case when value='x' then 1 else 0 end"))
# cumulative sum to get row numbers
df = df.withColumn('rownum', F.sum("row").over(Window().orderBy('order')))

# get rid of row terminator
df = df.filter(df['value'] != 'x')

# pivot to get answer
df = df.groupby('rownum').pivot('colname').agg(F.first("value"))
df = df.select(F.lit("x").alias("col1"), "col2", "col3", "col4")
df.show()

+----+-----+------+--------+
|col1| col2|  col3|    col4|
+----+-----+------+--------+
|   x| null|a: krb|    null|
|   x|c: HK| a: HP|    d: T|
|   x|c: CN|a: MSS|d: H-MSS|
+----+-----+------+--------+
```